# Marketing Cloud - Pass Date/Timestamp to Custom SF Field with Journey Object Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm hoping to be able to create a custom field in Salesforce, and update that field using the Journey Builder 'Object Activity'.

Ideally, at the end of a Journey, the Object Activity would pass a text string, such as "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss - Completed JourneyName", and the field in Salesforce would record multiple updates, creating a log of Journey activity.

Is this possible using MC Connect?

From what I can see, it looks like Update Options are limited to "Overwrite" and "Overwrite (only when null)". Is there a way to just add a value to a Text Area field without overwriting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "Append" update type for Salesforce update activities. If you are sending emails in your Journey, you could, however use [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) in your email to update your record. This would be a bit tricky because you would first have to use [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) to get the existing value in that field and then append your new date.

Also to add more complexity, Salesforce time format must match the format below AND there is a time difference as Marketing Cloud server time is in Central Time without observing Daylight Savings Time.

```
SET @updatetime = Format(@now, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Jackson!